# No service for type 'AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' has been registered. with custom provider (Net Core 6)

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-6.0

I try to implement custom UserStore and custom RoleStore

Implement interfaces

```
Public Interface ICustomRoleStore     
    Inherits IRoleStore(Of ApplcationRole)     
    Overloads Sub Dispose()     
    Overloads Function CreateAsync(role As ApplcationRole, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task(Of IdentityResult)     
    Overloads Function DeleteAsync(role As ApplcationRole, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task(Of IdentityResult)     
    Overloads Function FindByIdAsync(roleId As String, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task(Of ApplcationRole)     
    Overloads Function FindByNameAsync(normalizedRoleName As String, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task(Of ApplcationRole)     
    Overloads Function GetNormalizedRoleNameAsync(role As ApplcationRole, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task(Of String)     
    Overloads Function GetRoleIdAsync(role As ApplcationRole, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task(Of String)     
    Overloads Function GetRoleNameAsync(role As ApplcationRole, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task(Of String)     
    Overloads Function SetNormalizedRoleNameAsync(role As ApplcationRole, normalizedName As String, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task     
    Overloads Function SetRoleNameAsync(role As ApplcationRole, roleName As String, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task     
    Overloads Function UpdateAsync(role As ApplcationRole, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task(Of IdentityResult)     
End Interface
```

and

```
Public Interface ICustomUserStore
    Inherits IUserStore(Of ApplicationUser)
    Overloads Sub Dispose()
    Overloads Function CreateAsync(user As ApplicationUser, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task(Of IdentityResult)
    Overloads Function DeleteAsync(user As ApplicationUser, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task(Of IdentityResult)
    Overloads Function FindByIdAsync(userId As String, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task(Of ApplicationUser)
    Overloads Function FindByNameAsync(normalizedUserName As String, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task(Of ApplicationUser)
    Overloads Function GetNormalizedUserNameAsync(user As ApplicationUser, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task(Of String)
    Overloads Function GetUserIdAsync(user As ApplicationUser, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task(Of String)
    Overloads Function GetUserNameAsync(user As ApplicationUser, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task(Of String)
    Overloads Function SetNormalizedUserNameAsync(user As ApplicationUser, normalizedName As String, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task
    Overloads Function SetUserNameAsync(user As ApplicationUser, userName As String, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task
    Overloads Function UpdateAsync(user As ApplicationUser, cancellationToken As CancellationToken) As Task(Of IdentityResult)
End Interface
```

Then I have add Identity by the same way

```
Builder.Services.AddIdentity(Of ApplicationUser, ApplcationRole).AddUserStore(Of CustomUserStore).AddRoleStore(Of CustomRoleStore)()
```

It's look as enough to configure MS.Identity, but unexpectedly I receive

> InvalidOperationException: No service for type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]'
> has been registered.

Also I try to use various options like

```
    Builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(Sub(options)
                                                    options.LoginPath = "/User/Login"
                                                End Sub)
```

and

```
    Builder.Services.Configure(Of IdentityOptions)(Sub(options)
                                                       'Password settings.
                                                       options.Password.RequireDigit = True
                                                       options.Password.RequireLowercase = True
                                                       options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = True
                                                       options.Password.RequireUppercase = True
                                                       options.Password.RequiredLength = 6
                                                       options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1
                                                   End Sub)
```

and other options, but all times I failed. What I lost? What mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research I found a reason of this issue.

Standard injection to view is

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager
```

But because I configure service for ApplicationUser, than I must create this injection by the same way

```
@using MyBackendApi.Models
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
```